# Create a storyboard link in a TFS Work Item programatically

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-workitem

I want to create a storyboard link in a workitem programatically.

Here is what I am doing

```
RegisteredLinkType type = _workItem.Store.RegisteredLinkTypes["Storyboard"]; 

if (type != null) 
{

//path is a shared network location

ExternalLink el = new ExternalLink(type, path);     
_workItem.Links.Add(el); 
workItem.Save(); 
}
```

In this way the link is created but when I click on it, it gives malformed uri exception.

Comment: Sounds like path is wrong, can you compare a working "path" from one you added in VS and the one you are trying to use.

Comment: when i add the same path directly from visual studio it works fine

Comment: I have tried different paths with same result, paths are like this `\\sysName\\FolderName\FileName.pptx`

Comment: Don't you need to add `file:///` to the start?

Comment: I have checked and that dosen't work either

Comment: Can you get the URI from an existing one via the API?

Comment: It goes something like this `vstfs:///Requirements/Storyboard/%5c%5cSysName%5cWriteable+Share%5cStoryBoard%5cpowerpoint.pptx` the actual path is this `\\SysName\Writeable Share\StoryBoard\powerpoint.pptx`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a function like this to create the URI's:

```
String ConvertToTfsUri(String inputUncPath)
{
    return
        "vstfs:///Requirements/Storyboard/" + Uri.EscapeUriString(input);
}
```

This will escape the UNC Path and then create a TFS style URI.